# Populating Form with Options PHP/SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm working on a very simply html/php project and seem to be stuck already. I need to populate a drop down form with options that have values according to an sql query.
So far this is what I have in HTML:

```
<html>
<title>Drop Down</title>
<body>
    <form action = "query.php" method = "POST">
        <select name = "CategoryChoice">
            <?php
                $host = "localhost";
                $user = "user";
                $pass = "pass";
                $db = "cpsc421";
                mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
                mysql_select_db($db);
                $stmt = "SELECT name FROM category";
                $result = mysql_query($result);
                while(list($category) = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                    $option = '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category.'</option>';
                    echo $option;
                    }
            ?>

        </select>
        <input type = "submit" value = "ExecuteQuery"/>
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

I can load the page fine, so the html is working, but the drop down menu is empty. The php is failing in some way. I need each option's value attribute to equal values from the sql query. How can I perform this dynamically?

Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please avoid using `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$result = mysql_query($result);
```

to:

```
$result = mysql_query($stmt) or die(mysql_error());
```

You were using the wrong variable to get the query, and you weren't checking for errors (which would have let you know that you had a problem there).

Comment: I've fixed the silly error with the wrong variable in the mysql_query call, however I'm still getting an empty drop down! I know I am receiving values from the database correctly, is there anything wrong with the format of my option entries? Or maybe how I'm echoing them?

Comment: Looks OK to me. What do you see when you View Source?

Comment: No you were right, it is OK. Retested it and everything checks out! Thanks for the help Barmar, always the little things!